# HTML5 Geolocation For IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, geolocation

I have a link on the web page for detecting Current location of user. The HTML5 geolocation works on all browsers but not on IE8. I tried different polyfills like [this](https://github.com/estebanav/javascript-mobile-desktop-geolocation/blob/master/demo-no-simulation.html) OR [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Geolocation) but nothing seems to work out.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I know Geo location is supported in IE9 and above but is there any way or polyfill which can make it work for IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they would work on IE8 specifically, but there are some geolocation polyfills [listed on this Github repository](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). Not sure if you tried all these or not.

Oh and here is another useful site worth bookmarking in case you need any more polyfills: http://html5polyfill.com/. Some different polyfills for geolocation may be on there.

Comment: I tried the polyfills listed in the Github repository, but they didn't work.

Comment: Your best bet then is probably to use a PHP API/service like this one: http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php
Sorry that nothing else worked!

Comment: thanks. I think there is no other way than to handle through backend.